# Windows 2000 VB6 client not working with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application that I am migrating from SQL 2000 to 2008.
This has gone mostly smoothly.  The local machines running Win XP and the VB6 application are working.  One machine (only one I can get to directly) runs Win Server 2003 and it works OK.  However, the workstations at the remote location are running the VB6 app on Windows 2000.  Those do not work.

My question is: what might be missing or out-of-date on the Win 2000 machines, if anything, that would prevent them from working with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you give a little more information about any errors? What are you using to connect to the server? If you're using the SQL 2008 Native Client in your app, it requires XP SP2 or newer. [**System Requirements for SQL Server 2008 Native Client**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131002.aspx) Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Definately not using SQL 2008 Native Client.  Using MDAC that was installed with app 10 years ago.  Do not have access to machines.  However, do know that machines at local installation are Win XP also using MDAC KB870669.

Connection string is:
Driver=SQL Server;Server=z;Database=yy;App=XXXX;UID=me;PWD=sa;

With names changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: Also, VB program is using ADO and MDAC

Comment: Ok, then definitely start with updating MDAC like techie007 suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing which error message(s) you're getting, or what methods you are using to connect to the SQL server I'd say your first bet is to ensure the Win 2000 machine(s) have updated Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) installed.  You can get [MDAC 2.8 SP1 from MS here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=78CAC895-EFC2-4F8E-A9E0-3A1AFBD5922E&displaylang=en).

Comment: I will get remote tech to check MDAC and update in the morning.

Comment: Thanks, I did have the remote tech update MDAC as you suggest (also thanks to squillman).  But the problem turned out to be that all of the workstations at the remote location had an entry in the hosts file explicitly pointing to the IP address of the legacy server and, of course I shut that down when I started the upgraded server and put in a DNS entry to redirect the old server name to the new one.  Of course the hosts file entries made all that moot.

Comment: Good ol' HOSTS. ;)  Glad to hear you got it figured out.